# hex part of multiple packets given a pcap file

Tags: network-programming, pcap

Given a very huge pcap file or files. Using wireshark, I am able to get hexpart for one packet. I used the link [hex data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116644/how-to-copy-hex-data-of-captured-packet-form-wireshark). Can anyone tell me how we can do the same thing for multiple packets ? (need not be only using wireshark).

Comment: Suggested by the linked question... try `tshark -x -r <my_pcap>`. You can then either copy-paste from the terminal window or just redirect the output of tshark.

Comment: I want to know how to get hexstream for multiple packets. Answer was given for one packet using wireshark.